# Uppercase specific words in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Inside EditText I want to know how to capitalize on specific words. The code is below.

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        private static final String KEYWORD = "rain";
        private static final String KEYWORD1 = "music";

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            onSaveNote();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            onSaveNote();


            try {

                for (StyleSpan span : s.getSpans(0, s.length(), StyleSpan.class)) {
                    s.removeSpan(span);
                }

                // Add new spans for every occurrence of the keyword.
                int i = 0;
                while (i != -1) {
                    i = editText.getText().toString().indexOf(KEYWORD, i);
                    if (i != -1) {
                        s.setSpan(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()}, i, i + KEYWORD.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                    }

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

I tried searching for this but not found any. InputFilter doesn't work. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In `afterTextChanged()`, do the following:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    onSaveNote();
    String[] words = s.toString().split("\\s+");
    String output = "";
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(KEYWORD) || word.equalsIgnoreCase(KEYWORD1)) {
            output += word.toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault()) + " ";
        } else {
            output += word + " ";
        }
    }
    editText.setText(output.trim());
}
```

Comment: please check your logcat and tell me what the crash it. Don't forget to remove your old code in afterTextChanged()

Comment: W/AllCapsTransformationMethod: Caller did not enable length changes; not transforming text

Comment: No. I remove it.

Comment: is textAllCaps true in xml?

Comment: No. I don't have textAllCaps

Comment: is it crashing when you type the first word or when you type a space after the first word or when you start typing the second word in your edittext?

Comment: None of them. When I enter WriteActivity and it crash.

Comment: are you setting any text by default? like `editText.setText()` in your onCreate or onStart

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzs3imxfsyc5o1d/20200602_184905.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

If you know value of your text and start and end index of your text.

```
editText.getText().toString().substring(startIndex, endIndex).toUpperCase();
```

You can find start index in text like this:

```
editText.getText().toString().indexOf(KEYWORD)
```

and end index like this:

```
editText.getText().toString().indexOf(KEYWORD) + KEYWORD.length()
```